# how to differentiate 2 grid's while exporting to pdf

Tags: c#, datagridview, itext

i have 2 grid's which i need to export to pdf...

now i can export.. but

i can differentiate 2 grid's...meaning the 2 grids are adding in a single table..

i need space betweeen 2 grids so that i can differentiate...

how can i keep empty space between 2 grids....here is my code

gridview1: gvrpaList
gridview1: rptisslst

```
   protected void btnExportPDF_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)

  {

  Response.ContentType = "application/pdf";

Response.AddHeader("content-disposition",

"attachment;filename=GridViewExport.pdf");

Response.Cache.SetCacheability(HttpCacheability.NoCache);

StringWriter sw = new StringWriter();

HtmlTextWriter hw = new HtmlTextWriter(sw);

gvrpaList.AllowPaging = false;

//gvrpaList.DataBind();

gvrpaList.RenderControl(hw);

gvrpaList.HeaderRow.Style.Add("width", "15%");

gvrpaList.HeaderRow.Style.Add("font-size", "15px");

gvrpaList.Style.Add("text-decoration", "none"); 

gvrpaList.Style.Add("font-family", "Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;");

gvrpaList.Style.Add("font-size", "8px");

rptisslst.AllowPaging = false;

rptisslst.RenderControl(hw);

rptisslst.HeaderRow.Style.Add("width", "15%");

rptisslst.HeaderRow.Style.Add("font-size", "15px");

rptisslst.Style.Add("text-decoration", "none");


rptisslst.Style.Add("font-family", "Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;");
rptisslst.Style.Add("font-size", "8px");


StringReader sr = new StringReader(sw.ToString());

Document pdfDoc = new Document(PageSize.A4, 10f, 10f, 10f, 0f);

HTMLWorker htmlparser = new HTMLWorker(pdfDoc);

PdfWriter.GetInstance(pdfDoc, Response.OutputStream);

 byte[] byteArr = Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes(sw.ToString());
 MemoryStream stream = new MemoryStream(byteArr);

 StreamReader stre = new StreamReader(stream);

  pdfDoc.Open();

  htmlparser.Parse(stre);

  pdfDoc.Close();

  Response.Write(pdfDoc);

  Response.End();
   }
   public override void VerifyRenderingInServerForm(Control control)
  {
  // verifies the control is rendered here
   }
```

Answer (score 0):

You could try to add a line break:

```
gvrpaList.RenderControl(hw);
hw.Write("<br />");
rptisslst.RenderControl(hw);
```